# Assign new unique key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am trying to make a memory game in next js. I am taking a list of letters of the cards and making 2 of each then randomizing them. This part is work. However, because I made a copy of all the object in the array, I no longer have a unique key. I tried two was of adding a key but both failed.

try 1.

```
const lettersX2 = letters.concat(letters)
    .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    .map((card) => ({...card, order: Math.random() }));
```

the did not seem to do any thing.

Try 2.

```
const lettersX2 = letters.concat(letters)
    .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    .concat(cards.order = Math.random());
```

this added a new object at the end of the.

How can a add a new unique key to my array?

Comment: It's not really clear what it is you desire. Every element in the array still has an index which is unique, what kind of unique key do you want and what for? Let's say you have `const letters = ["A", "B", "C"];` and then you concatenate and shuffle and you'll get something like this `[ 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B' ]`.  What would be the desired result for your unique index?

Comment: @Mushroomator, Mostly, I am trying to get rid of the "next-dev.js?3515:20 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."  that come up because I do not have a unique key.